# "release a burden"?

Tags: phrases

I was wondering if it is correct to say "I finally release a burden?"

Or should I say "I finally get released from a burden, as like "release somebody from something"?

What are some other usual ways to express the same meaning?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The word *burden* is [derived from](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=burden&searchmode=none) a Proto Germanic word that means "that which is borne (or carried)."

The modern English word *[burden](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/burden)* has the same meaning both in metaphoric and literal senses.  That is, a burden is a load that is carried on one's back, or a responsibility that is carried on one's shoulders.

Keeping that in mind, "releasing a burden" makes sense, since presumably you have control over the thing you are carrying.  I think "released from a burden" sounds odd, and implies that the cart is driving the horse, if you follow my meaning.

I agree with Chris that "laying down a burden" is very common. Again, if you think of literally carrying a load, this makes sense.

You might also say you have "discharged your responsibilities or duties" if you are talking about a metaphorical burden, or "taken a load off" if you are talking about a physical burden (or even sometimes a metaphorical one).

Answer (score 4):

One "lays down a burden", or has "laid down a burden". One might "cast off" a burden as well, particularly if the burden was holding you back from something.

Comment: Thanks! Is it correct to say "I finally release a burden?"
Or should I say "I finally get released from a burden, as like "release somebody from something"?

Comment: I would say "I have finally been released FROM a burden", since you're the thing that is presumably roaming free now.

Comment: I wouldn't want to make too much of it, but to me there's a suggestion of mixed metaphors in any expression using both *burden* and *release*. A *burden* is something that weighs you down, but *release* suggests either opening a previously-closed escape route, or disentangling something that had you tied up. So I just don't think I'd put both words in the same sentence.

Comment: People often speak of 'spiritual burdens' or 'emotional burdens';  virtually all of these can be "released" as much as "lain down".

One can "be released from" a burden if it has been imposed by an outside authority, say a boss, or a prison system.

Answer (score 1):

One can also be *relieved of* a burden.